# Application to download data from one database to another

Tags: .net

I'm planning to write a .NET Windows Forms application to download data from one database to another on scheduled time. 
So I need select one from these two options

1. Create a windows form with a Timer control and handle starting of download process through the code and keep application running forever on the server.
2. Create a windows form and run downloading method on form load and use Windows Scheduler to start the program at a given time and exit the program when download is completed.

What do I have to consider selecting between above approaches and what are the advantages/disadvantages ?

**NOTE:** Downloading is done from multiple tables (like Item, Supplier) so there may be a requiremet to stop one or few table syncing so I guess this needs a UI.

Comment: Is there a reason for it being WinForms? Is a UI required? If not I would recommend a scheduled SSIS job if using SQL Server.

Comment: Sounds overdone. Perform these jobs in the database itself. Unless you must have a UI but seems to me that copy data from one db to another does not need a UI

Comment: @PhilMurray Downloading is done from multiple tables (like Item, Supplier) so there may be a requiremet to stop one or few table syncing so I guess this needs a UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did want a .NET application to do it, as opposed to handling it in the database server, then you would want one of:

1. A console application that is run by the Windows scheduler on the database server, assuming the server is Windows.
2. A Windows service with a timer (and by definition, no GUI).

In both those cases I would use config files for input and Log4Net for output. You can add a graphical test harness project to the solution to provide a testing UI in either case.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using windows forms just create SSIS Jobs using SQL Server.

Just create your Integration Services Package or Stored Procedures that get and send data from database to another then just schedule job on SQL Server.

Check this link: [Automating Database Administration with SQL Server Agent](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ss/sql_server_agent_3.htm)

Best Regards